# Bootstrap 4.5 table TR followed by a TH

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive

I am wondering why bootstrap 4.5 put a  right after a  element, like this (official Bootstrap site), and why does `scope="row` means ?

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      **<th scope="row">1</th>**
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      **<th scope="row">2</th>**
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      **<th scope="row">3</th>**
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A th scope it's not a "bootstrap thing". It specifies whether a header cell is a header for a column, row, or group of columns or rows.
Answering your question about scope=row, it indicates that this th will be the header for the row you're writting following.
You can find more info here: [HTML th scope Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_th_scope.asp)

Comment: Thank you, Already read many articles on the web. Is it valide with w3c ?